# CKEditor and iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, path, ckeditor

I'm experiencing stuff with CKEditor. I read the doc, but I can't find a way to do what I'm trying to do.(I'm in Java, in a jsp page)

I have a path

```
String path = request.getContextPath();
```

And I need to call this path

```
<%=path%>/docX/Controller
```

What I have is very basic:

```
<div id="editor">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</div>
<script>
    initSample();
</script>
```

That works very well, but I want to add content when the page load.

I tried to manually add an iframe in the code with my path, such as

```
<iframe src="<%=path%>/docX/Controller"></iframe>
```

But it shows something like this : http://docs.cksource.com/images/9/93/CKEditor_iframe_example1.png

Which is normal if I understood well. If I click on "preview" I'll see what I'm suppose to see. But I want to see it at first and I want to be able to edit it.

The file it will return will be a .html file. So I must get the 'innerHTML' from that file and put it somehow in the editor. It doesn't have to be an `iframe` if there's an easier way to get the data.

Now I'm trying to get the html from the iframe and put it into a `<p>`. What I got so far looks like this :

```
<%
    String path = request.getContextPath();
%>
<div class="main">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-width-100">
            <div id="editor">
                <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                <iframe id="frame" src="<%=path%>/docX/Controller"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    initSample();
    var iframe = document.getElementById("frame");
    var iframe_contents = iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
    alert(iframe_contents);
</script>
```

My `alert()` shows an empty string, but if I click on preview, I can see the text.

Any kind of help is always appreciated.

EDIT: My html file only have "test" inside it. Nothing like `<html>` `<head>` and stuff. I tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var test = $("#frame").contents().find("html").html();
     alert(test);
})
```

But it returns `<html></html><body></body>`

EDIT 2:

I changed it for

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var mydocument = document.getElementById("frame").contentDocument;
      var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
      var content = serializer.serializeToString(mydocument);
      alert(content);
})
```

My result is : `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre></body></html>`

If I open my .html file, all I see is `test`

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question so if someone has the same issue, he could try this solution.

So I removed the `<iframe>` from my CKEditor and I added an empty `<p>`. I simply took the returned data of my URL and put it in that `<p>`.

```
<%
    String path = request.getContextPath();
%>
<div class="main">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-width-100">
            <div id="editor">
                <p id="content"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    initSample();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get('<%=path%>/docX/Controller').then(function(responseData) {
            $("#content").append(responseData);
        });

    })
</script>
```

In my case, `responseData` returns "test". It will also take properties, if your text is bold for exemple.

This will work in IE. But to make it work in chrome, in my case, it will return `object XMLDocument`. I had to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<%=path%>/docX/Controller',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data); 
    }
});
```